# Wampserver MySQL will not start

Tags: mysql, installation, wampserver

Tried setting up Wampserver, got orange icon, Apache is running, MySQL is not, below is MySQL Log:

```
2014-06-03 21:49:21 2412 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-06-03 21:49:21 2412 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-06-03 21:49:21 2412 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-06-03 21:49:21 2412 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-06-03 21:49:21 2412 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-06-03 21:49:21 2412 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-06-03 21:49:21 2412 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-06-03 21:49:21 2412 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-06-03 21:49:21 2412 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-06-03 21:49:21 2412 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 1625977
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Binlog end
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-06-03 21:49:22 2412 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-06-03 21:49:30 2412 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625987
2014-06-03 21:49:30 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-06-03 21:49:30 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-06-03 21:49:30 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-06-03 21:49:30 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-06-03 21:49:30 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-06-03 21:49:30 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-06-03 21:49:30 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-06-03 21:49:30 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-06-03 21:49:30 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-06-03 21:49:30 2412 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-06-03 21:49:30 2412 [Note] wampmysqld: Arrêt du serveur terminé

2014-06-03 21:49:58 5280 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-06-03 21:49:58 5280 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-06-03 21:49:58 5280 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-06-03 21:49:58 5280 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-06-03 21:49:58 5280 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-06-03 21:49:58 5280 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-06-03 21:49:58 5280 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-06-03 21:49:58 5280 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-06-03 21:49:58 5280 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 1625987
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Binlog end
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-06-03 21:49:59 5280 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-06-03 21:50:00 5280 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625997
2014-06-03 21:50:00 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-06-03 21:50:00 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-06-03 21:50:00 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-06-03 21:50:00 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-06-03 21:50:00 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-06-03 21:50:00 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-06-03 21:50:00 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-06-03 21:50:00 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-06-03 21:50:00 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-06-03 21:50:00 5280 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-06-03 21:50:00 5280 [Note] wampmysqld: Arrêt du serveur terminé

2014-06-03 21:50:47 520 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-06-03 21:50:47 520 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-06-03 21:50:47 520 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-06-03 21:50:47 520 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-06-03 21:50:47 520 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-06-03 21:50:47 520 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-06-03 21:50:47 520 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-06-03 21:50:47 520 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 1625997
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Binlog end
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-06-03 21:50:48 520 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-06-03 21:50:49 520 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1626007
2014-06-03 21:50:49 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-06-03 21:50:49 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-06-03 21:50:49 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-06-03 21:50:49 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-06-03 21:50:49 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-06-03 21:50:49 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-06-03 21:50:49 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-06-03 21:50:49 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-06-03 21:50:49 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-06-03 21:50:49 520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-06-03 21:50:49 520 [Note] wampmysqld: Arrêt du serveur terminé

2014-06-03 21:50:57 3548 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-06-03 21:50:57 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-06-03 21:50:57 3548 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-06-03 21:50:57 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-06-03 21:50:57 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-06-03 21:50:57 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-06-03 21:50:57 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-06-03 21:50:57 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 1626007
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Binlog end
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-06-03 21:50:58 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-06-03 21:50:59 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1626017
2014-06-03 21:50:59 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-06-03 21:50:59 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-06-03 21:50:59 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-06-03 21:50:59 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-06-03 21:50:59 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-06-03 21:50:59 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-06-03 21:50:59 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-06-03 21:50:59 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-06-03 21:50:59 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-06-03 21:50:59 3548 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-06-03 21:50:59 3548 [Note] wampmysqld: Arrêt du serveur terminé

2014-06-03 21:57:31 3020 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-06-03 21:57:31 3020 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-06-03 21:57:31 3020 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-06-03 21:57:31 3020 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-06-03 21:57:31 3020 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-06-03 21:57:31 3020 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-06-03 21:57:31 3020 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-06-03 21:57:31 3020 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-06-03 21:57:31 3020 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 1626017
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Binlog end
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-06-03 21:57:32 3020 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-06-03 21:57:33 3020 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1626027
2014-06-03 21:57:33 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-06-03 21:57:33 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-06-03 21:57:33 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-06-03 21:57:33 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-06-03 21:57:33 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-06-03 21:57:33 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-06-03 21:57:33 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-06-03 21:57:33 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-06-03 21:57:33 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-06-03 21:57:33 3020 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-06-03 21:57:33 3020 [Note] wampmysqld: Arrêt du serveur terminé
```

Any suggestions?  Do I have something on Port 3306 that needs to be removed?  If so, how?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the output of `netstat -banpx TCP`? you will need administrative prevailing for this.

Comment: http://www.tng.lythgoes.net/wiki/index.php?title=WampServer_MYSQL_port_changes&setlang=en

Comment: I changed the Port to 3307 from 3306 on my my.ini file under c:wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/my.ini and got Wampserver green and running, but how do I clear Port 3306? I remember trying to learn PHP MySQL a long time ago and used Xampp or Zend, but deleted those, and I figured that instance of MySQL was deleted with them. I guess not, so any suggestions on removing another instance of MySQL considering that's the only thing I could think of that would be occupying Port 3306?

Comment: netstat -banpx TCP just gives me options: -a, -b, -e, -f, etc.  netstat -a lets me know there is something listening on Port 3306, but doesn't give me any other information.  You can probably tell by now that I have no idea what I'm doing, so if there are easy steps somewhere on how to remove whatever is listening on Port 3306, that info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `netstat -ab`. BTW which OS version? `-b` displays the executable involved. also check if another MySQL server is already running `services.msc`

Comment: -ab and -b both say "This requested operation requires elevation".

Comment: I found another instance of my.ini suggested by Andrew's link from Zend that was apparently not deleted from my Program Files when the program was deleted.  Can I just delete that leftover Zend folder to open Port 3306, or do I have to do something more elaborate?

Comment: you should actually uninstall MySQL service running. You cannot just delete the folder. and for `-b` option you will require `run as Administrator`

Comment: The OS is Window Vista 32 Bit by the way.  I did find the Zend MySQL running in services.  I stopped it and disabled it on "Startup Type".  will doing that and deleting the old Zend folder completely remove it so I will never have to think about it again?

Comment: I think you can use `sc` command to remove MySQL Server. `sc delete <service-name>` Where `<service-name>` is the name from the Services list. ot you can run `"C:\Path\To\Mysql Server\bin\mysqld" --remove`. Also check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html)

Comment: Ok, I removed it with sc delete as well.  My Wampserver is running and life is good.  Thanks for all the help from everyone.  I would have literally pulled out every hair from my head without this site and your help.

Comment: Nice to hear it worked for you. Hope you will also be helping somebody someday :)